# Has Unity mobile-like multiplayer system?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Has unity any tools or services to create a multiplayer like in mobile games, where all online is based on clan system, chat and some stuff like arena or rating?
If has, do you know someone of them (links or guides are optional)?

I read all the documentation and watched some videos connected to the problem, but as I understand it is all about real time multiplayer.

Comment: The features you mentionned are "Meta" features and dont require gameplay replication. No Unity don't provide these out of the box you'll have to roll your server or use some PaaS services that might help. Think firebase, gamespark etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your question. Are you asking if Unity has some tools to create a full multiplayer game experience (matchmaking, voice, chat, etc.)?

Unity's UNet is deprecated and they are developing a new system. Maybe check here:
[New Unity system](https://unity.com/solutions/real-time-multiplayer?_ga=2.108348033.244672583.1579378660-1108096207.1516393295)

I would recommend the Photon engine. It basically has everything you need for a multiplayer game and it's free to get started. 
[Photon engine](https://www.photonengine.com/en-us/Photon)

Comment: The multiplayer I talk about isn't realtime. It's like in mobile (idle-rpg) games, where you can check the profile of other players, join clan or join some events, but the gameplay side doesn't need a realtime multiplayer.